# How to remove Specific values from Shared Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Am using SharedPreferences to store list of values. What I need is to remove specific value from SharedPreferences.Below is my code am using to remove. But its not working.

```
 prefs= DetailActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("itemFKID",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        edit=prefs.edit();
                        //edit.clear();
                        edit.remove(itemFkId);
                        edit.commit();
```

Below is Screenshot that contains values even after edit.remove() compiles.
[image: Debugging Image]

Here am inserting values into SharedPreferences

```
prefs= DetailActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("itemFKID",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                edit=prefs.edit();

                for (int i = 0; i < Config.favouritesList.size(); i++) {
                    edit.putString("itemFKIDValue" +i, Config.favouritesList.get(i));
                }
                edit.putInt("itemFKIDLength", Config.favouritesList.size());
                edit.commit();
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove and item from the list or the whole list?

Comment: Trying to remove a item from the list

Comment: You will need to first get your hashMap, remove the id from it, then resave the new map.

Comment: Can you plz help me with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the mistake. Key passed in remove() is wrong. Instead of edit.remove(itemFKIDValue) I have used edit.remove(itemFkID). Thanks for the time guys.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `SharedPreferences.Editor` has two bits that are relevant to your question:

> All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()

And

> when committing back to the preferences, all removals are done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after put methods on this editor

So you'll have to step over the `commit()` call before you see the value removed.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have updated my Screenshot Image.. Still the problem occurs.@Ben P.

Comment: Can you post the code where you insert the item into your SharedPreferences?

Comment: I have added in the qustion